# Checkbox checked with jquery.cookie

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-cookie

I found a wonderful code, that does exactly what i need. But, a little change is still required.

I want "Checkbox3" and "Checkbox4" to be checked by default, but when I'll uncheck, for example "Checkbox3", it'll stay unchecked, untill its cookie is deleted, or until I'll check it again. Same goes to "Checkbox4".

Thanks for your help.

Here is the code http://jsfiddle.net/artmouse/22e8f/

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test: jQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cookie1 = $.cookie("cookie1");
    var cookie2 = $.cookie("cookie2");
    var cookie3 = $.cookie("cookie3");
    var cookie4 = $.cookie("cookie4");
    !( cookie1 == "changed" ) || $('.Checkbox1').attr('checked',true);
    !( cookie2 == "changed" ) || $('.Checkbox2').attr('checked',true);
    !( cookie3 == "changed" ) || $('.Checkbox3').attr('checked',true);
    !( cookie4 == "changed" ) || $('.Checkbox4').attr('checked',true);
    $('.Checkbox1').change(function () {               
        $('#displaySection1').toggle(!this.checked);
        if( this.checked ) {
            $.cookie("cookie1", "changed");
        } else {
            $.cookie("cookie1", null);
        }         
    }).change();
    $('.Checkbox2').change(function () {
        $('#displaySection2').toggle(!this.checked);
        if( this.checked ) {
            $.cookie("cookie2", "changed");
        } else {
            $.cookie("cookie2", null);
        }         
    }).change(); //ensure visible state matches initially
    $('.Checkbox3').change(function () {
        $('#displaySection3').toggle(!this.checked);
        if( this.checked ) {
            $.cookie("cookie3", "changed");
        } else {
            $.cookie("cookie3", null);
        }         
    }).change(); //ensure visible state matches initially
    $('.Checkbox4').change(function () {
        $('#displaySection4').toggle(!this.checked);
        if( this.checked ) {
            $.cookie("cookie4", "changed");
        } else {
            $.cookie("cookie4", null);
        }         
    }).change(); //ensure visible state matches initially
});  //end function
</script>
<script>
$(function () {
  var cookieD = $.cookie("cookieDates");
  !( cookieD == "changed" ) || $('.always').attr('checked',true); 
  $('.always').change(function () {               
     $('#dates').toggle(!this.checked);
     if( this.checked ) {
         $.cookie("cookieDates", "changed");
     } else {
         $.cookie("cookieDates", null);
     }         
  }).change();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input class="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />Hide Section 1<br />
        <input class="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" />Hide Section 2<br />
        <input class="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" />Hide Section 3<br />
        <input class="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" />Hide Section 4<br />
        <br />

        <div id="content">
            <div id="displaySection1">
                <strong>Section 1</strong>
                <br />
                Content for section 1 goes here.
                <br /><br />
            </div>
            <div id="displaySection2">
                <strong>Section 2</strong>
                <br />
                Content for section 2 goes here.
                <br /><br />
            </div>
            <div id="displaySection3">
                <strong>Section 3</strong>
                <br />
                Content for section 3 goes here.
                <br /><br />
            </div>
            <div id="displaySection4">
                <strong>Section 4</strong>
                <br />
                Content for section 4 goes here.
                <br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: the problem is I don't know how to set some of checkboxes to be checked by default. Now they all are unchecked, until I click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function section(checkbox, section, cookieName, defaultStatus) {
        var cookie = $.cookie(cookieName);

        var $chk = $(checkbox).prop('checked', cookie == undefined ? defaultStatus : cookie == '1' ? true : false);
        $chk.change(function () {
            $(section).toggle(!this.checked);
            $.cookie(cookieName, this.checked ? 1 : 0);
        }).change();
    }

    section('.Checkbox1', '#displaySection1', 'cookie1', false);
    section('.Checkbox2', '#displaySection2', 'cookie2', true);
    section('.Checkbox3', '#displaySection3', 'cookie3', false);
    section('.Checkbox4', '#displaySection4', 'cookie4', true);

}); //end function
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zExKC/)

Comment: That’s exactly what I wanted! I checked it in Opera, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, even IE7. Works everywhere. Many thanks!